# Does it make sense to provide alt text for labelled icon images?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

Alt text for images is HTML 101, but does it make sense when that alt text would be the same as a label immediately following it? To me, it seems redundant for people using screen readers to hear it twice. Here's an example just so it's abundantly clear:

```
<nav>
  <ul>

    <li>
      <a href="/chameleons.html">
        <img src="chameleons_icon.png" alt="chameleons">
        Chameleons
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/beardies.html">
        <img src="beardies_icon.png" alt="beardies">
        Beardies
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/basilisks.html">
        <img src="basilisks_icon.png" alt="basilisks">
        Basilisks
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/iguanas.html">
        <img src="iguanas_icon.png" alt="iguanas">
        Iguanas
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks for your input!

**Amendment:** For the sake of validation, should I just use `alt=""` or should I use background images?

Comment: Did you mean "Addendum", i.e. an additional question to your original question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Section 4.7.1.1 of W3C HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#alt) has a pretty huge list covering many common use cases of the `img` element and its `alt` attribute.

Your use case appears to be that of ["A graphical representation of some of the surrounding text."](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#a-graphical-representation-of-some-of-the-surrounding-text) Here's what the spec says:

> In many cases, the image is actually just supplementary, and its presence merely reinforces the surrounding text. In these cases, the `alt` attribute must be present but its value must be the empty string.
>
> In general, an image falls into this category if removing the image doesn't make the page any less useful, but including the image makes it a lot easier for users of visual browsers to understand the concept.

Therefore the `alt` attribute can (and, in fact, *must*) be empty in your case, as the images are merely there to support text that's already part of the main content and as you've stated, duplicating the content would be unnecessary and obtrusive:

```
<li>
  <a href="/chameleons.html">
    <img src="chameleons_icon.png" alt="">
    Chameleons
  </a>
</li>
```

You could take this one step further and mark everything up using a `figure` and `figcaption`, eliminating the need for an `alt` attribute altogether as the alt text is then provided via the `figcaption`:

```
<li>
  <a href="/chameleons.html">
    <figure>
      <img src="chameleons_icon.png">
      <figcaption>Chameleons</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</li>
```

> For the sake of validation, should I just use `alt=""` or should I use background images?

A validator can't tell you if having an empty `alt` attribute is appropriate; it can only tell you if you've left out an `alt` attribute that is required in that context.

So this comes down to the nature of your content, or even personal preference. If the image is a meaningful part of your content it's highly recommended that the image be included in the markup; `background-image` is intended for decorative visuals. But it's really up to you.

Comment: Dynamite answer. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer, You might add "in this case, use css if possible"

Comment: @Adam: See the last paragraph.

Comment: in addition to `alt=""` you would also want to add `role="presentation"`

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a user-experience-design problem.

Attribute `alt` is designed in old days when the network bandwidth is quite small, to describe the content of the image once it fails to load.

Understanding this, **the `alt` attribute is not necessary here**, especially when it duplicates the label text.

But it would cause problem if the images fail to load. Here are some alternative methods that can fix this.

First choice is, consider using `background-image` as the `<a>` tag instead of inserting an image inside it. No ugly image would ever appear. And better to try CSS Sprites.

Here is the code if you do not use CSS Sprites.

CSS:

```
a.nav-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 24px; /* use the width of your image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a.nav-icon-chameleons {
  background-image: url(chameleons_icon.png);
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="nav-icon nav-icon-chameleons" href="/chameleons.html">
  Chameleons
</a>
```

Another choice, which is much popular in these days, is using SVG, or font icons. See http://fontawesome.io/ if you could find some icons that would help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree that using background images is one solution. I had been considering that and it may very well be correct. However, reading your answer, it seems you may have misunderstood. The icon image does not contain text– it's just a normal pictograph icon accompanied by descriptive plain text– so I don't think there's an accessibility issue if the image fails to load. Also, I didn't find the relevance of using CSS sprites or SVG. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: CSS sprites is good, it could reduce the number of server requests and save bandwidth. You have four images here and each of them will send an HTTP request to your server. Using CSS sprites, combine four images into one, and use `background-position` to locate for each nav item, you will get the same effect with a better web performance. Indeed, ignore the SVG solution~~